# Can you add a company field in the user profile ?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Hello,

Most of the people answering and posting on serverfault are IT professionals, so a majority belong to a company or another and they can have a bias in their answer.

Is it possible for people to add the company they work for so other member can see it?

I know it will based on honesty, but that all the purpose of  this website. :-D

Regards

Answer (score 7):

You can mention your company in the "About Me" field if you want. I don't think it's worth it to clutter up user profile pages with a dozen fields.

Answer (score 4):

[alt text http://i28.tinypic.com/2lnvi8i.jpg](http://i28.tinypic.com/2lnvi8i.jpg)

Comment: Needs dropshadows!

Comment: @Shog9 you think that's where the DV came from?

Comment: I can't imagine any other reason for DVing this answer. Your hand-drawn circle is exquisite!

Comment: Symetric, anti-aliased and perfect red. That's a clear +1

Comment: Rex M: Quality, handcrafted red circles since 1998.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can add (nearly) anything they want to their profile. However, I don't think there's a need or reason to add a specific `company` field. I imagine many user's would not want to share this information (and unfortunately, some I'm sure do not have a job currently) and I'm not sure how much value it would add. Perhaps you could research a person and their company to determine any bias in regards to a specific answer, but if you're analyzing a situation you should be testing the answers you receive against your situation anyway. Additionally, the voting system should handle a case where a poor solutions, whether they're posted by someone with a vested interest in that solution or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use your public profile's About Me section.

You don't need all of those fields to fill out because most of the time they are going to be pretty useless and most people aren't going to care who you work for.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to support your company within your profile you could use the website field. If your company is known by others and/or is publicly listed then you would almost always have a website.